# how to replace space with hyphen '-' in asp.net Url routing while passing parameter from html (.aspx) page

Tags: c#, html

I have the following pages:

1. landing_page.aspx (products page)
2. product_description.aspx  (for showing the product description)

I am passing my product name from the landing_page to the product_description page on the url like this:

```
<a href="product-description/<%#Eval("Product_name")%>" >
```

where "product-description" is my URL routing string.

I am getting these results:

```
http://localhost:33891/product-description/shifon %20scarf%201%20meter
```

or

```
http://localhost:33891/product-description/shifon%20scarf%201%20meter
```

I want it to be like this:

http://localhost:33891/product-description/shifon-scarf-1-meter

The problem is that the names of my products have space in between which becomes %20 in the url. How should I replace the space or %20 with Hyphens '-' before passing it to URL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the return of this function

```
public static string ClearnUrl(string title)
    {
        string Product_name = title.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-");
        //Removes invalid character like .,-_ etc
        Product_name = Regex.Replace(Product_name, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]", ""); 
        return Product_name;
    }
```

Comment: Dear Karim Fahmy,
thankyou very much...
your answer really helped me and it is solved now
thankyou once again...